# Do sigils make source code easier to read?

Tags: programming-languages, readability

In most programming languages, variables do not have identifying characters like they do in PHP. In PHP you must prefix a variable with the `$` character.

Example;

```
 var $foo = "something";
 echo $foo;
```

I'm developing a new scripting language for a business application, and my target users do not have a programming background. Do these characters make code easier to read and use?

One reason PHP uses the `$` is because without it PHP can't tell if a name is a function reference or variable reference. This is because the language allows strange references to functions. So the `$` symbol helps the parser separate the namespace.

I don't have this problem in my parser. So my question is purely on readability and ease of use. I have coded for so many years in PHP that when I see `$foo` it's easy for me to identify this as a variable. Am I just giving a bias preference to this identifier?

Comment: IMO, code is more readable without sigils

Comment: @JanDvorak +1 for giving a me new word of the day. I shall try to use `sigils` three times today in conversations.

Comment: IMO It depends if your editor has syntax highlighting.

Comment: @CodeBeard the editor will be a textarea in a browser. Unless I use a JS editor that supports custom highlighting (that would be nice to have actually).

Comment: this looks cool: http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/?page=editArea

Comment: If you use `var $x = ...` or `type $x = ...` then I think $ is overkill. If you just had `$x = ...` then it could be worth doing. Especially if you don't want to support syntax highlighting in common editors. However, as a preference, I don't like `sigils`

Comment: If it is just a readability issue why not work this out with the actual users of the language and get feedback from them? <br/>
This assumes that you have easy access to your users of course.

Comment: sigils are like a enforced hungarian notation

Comment: As far as *which* sigil to use, I would recommend against `$` because currency symbols make little sense in a programming language. Multi-token and case-insensitive identifiers might be more sensible: `account ages = get account age (get friends of "Matthew")`

Comment: @JonPurdy great point Jon. This is a for a financial app and I forgot that users would be confused by `$` for anything other than currency.

Comment: About editors: http://ace.c9.io is a very interesting and well tested editor for code.

Comment: @CodeBeard Good editors understand the language's actual syntax and don't just key off sigils.

Comment: @RossPatterson I agree. How soon will these support this new language?

Comment: @CodeBeard Well, PHP isn't new, it's been around for almost 20 years, and Wikipedia lists about 50 editors that understand it.  The OP's new language won't have any support from any editor unless he writes it himself, and sigils won't change that.

Comment: @RossPatterson this second part is my point, I think :) PHP is a choice I don't make right now.

Comment: @CodeBeard No argument from me.  Just pointing out that, absent a language-author-written editor or add-in, syntax-aware editing for a new and minor language is a lost cause.

Comment: PHP has sigils because Perl had them.  Perl had sigils because sh had them.  The Bourne shell, developed in the late 70s, had them because sigils greatly simplify parsing when you're on a machine with a sub-MHz CPU and a megabyte of RAM.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething: The more fundamental reason that the Bourne shell had sigils was that it also decided to make quotation marks optional.  `program $filename` means a totally different thing from `program filename`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The actual technical possibilites and limitations are nothing of the sort as are suggested throughout this thread. Let's clear out those first.

Here's what $ is making possible in PHP:

- Variable variables
- Variables with keyword name e.g. `$return` or being able to use same name for a variable and a functon/constant e.g. `$__FILE__`

Limitations or features that are unrelated to the $ prefix:

- The implementation otherwise being unable to tell difference between functions and variables
- PHP string interpolation or template syntax
- Required variable declaration

That means there is no technical reason you couldn't have

```
foo = "something";
echo foo;
```

or

```
foo = "something";
echo "foo = $foo";
//would print
//foo = something
```

However you cannot have (assuming `return` is a keyword)

```
return = "something";
```

Without serious complications. If you used a prefix like `$`, then it would not 
have been any problem.

It's an opinion but I believe a sigil would be worth it for non programmers since it enables them to use keywords
as variable names, to them it would otherwise look like arbitrary limitation :P

Comment: About `return = "something";`, C# has "contextual keywords", which is also an option worth checking out when designing languages.

Comment: @luiscubal writing that in C# non-surprisingly requires a sigil, so if you want that code to be compiled, you need to write `@return = "something;"`. There is some amount of contextual keywords, yes, but making all of them contextual would mean much more complicated implementation.

Answer (score 7):

Sigils actually make a lot more sense in perl, where they provide a certain amount of type checking.  In php they don't help much outside of templating.  You can get a sense of their usefulness and readability by looking around at different languages.  Hardly any use them.

In an end user targeted language I'm working on, I even go further, making identifiers case insensitive and allowing spaces and apostrophes.  That lets me make variable names like `Karl's height` that are much closer to natural languages.

Comment: +1 for spaces in variables, but I have no idea how to implement that. Not sure I'd find that easier to read either. I'm just not use to it.

Comment: I like the idea. But I would hate to write the parser for a language with space's in the identifier. :-) `At Karl's for the night = true;`

Comment: But it would be interesting to see all these standards that we add to the top of a language to help us read it. Rather than be manually checked by an external tool but become part of the language definition. That way we can't have pointless arguments about identifier names in the coding standards (as they are in the language).

Comment: Case insensitivity has the problem of internationalization, though. If you allow characters from many languages, you may run into names that are "the same" in some locales, but not in others.

Comment: Allowing whitespace in variables isn't a big deal in principle - it just means a grammar rule for identifiers that allows multiple words. However, it does mean other things may not be possible in the grammar without creating ambiguity. For example, in Haskell, `map sum` is a partially-applied function call - the function `sum` is passed as a parameter to `map`. But both of those are just library names, so with multi-word identifiers, the compiler couldn't know if `map sum` is one multi-word identifier or a function application based on two single-word identifiers.

Answer (score 7):

Years ago, I learned Applesoft Basic.  Strings were always suffixed with `$` and arrays had a suffix of `%`.  Thats just how the language worked.  You looked at something, you knew what it was.  I never did delve too far into the interpreter to understand why this was the case or the design decisions that made it so.

---

The sigil in php comes from its perl influence (which was influenced by `awk` and `sh`).  The sigil in perl is quite a bit more than just `$` as it can identify many different types:

- `$` scalar
- `@` list
- `%` hash
- `&` codeblock
- `*` typeglob

The sigil identifies what part of the symbol table structure you are looking at.  Behind the scenes, the symbol table entry for foo (accessed via `*foo` - the typeglob) has everything that may be a foo.  There is `$foo`, `@foo`, `%foo`, the [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html) `foo`, `&foo`, the filehandle foo, etc...

This also allows making an alias of one variable to another:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$foo = "foo";
@qux = (1,2);
*bar = \$foo;
*bar = \@qux;

print "$bar @bar\n";
```

This prints `foo 1 2` - in perl, this is what the sigils are *really* for, not that you should do this but rather that there is this behind the scenes thing that they do.

The sigils aren't there so much for readability, but rather so that one can have `$foo` and `@foo` without having a collision in the namespace (compare other languages where one cannot have both `int foo; int[] foo;`)

---

Sigils for readability are something that is learned as part of any language - reading the syntax.  You could, hypothetically, enforce the type itself (as hungarian notation) to be part of the identifier.

Something in lex along the lines of:

```
typeChar  [is]
capLetter [A-Z]
letter    [a-z]
digit     [0-9]
%%
{typeChar}{capLetter}(letter}|{digit})* { prientif("iddentifier");}
%%
```

And then you could have code like

```
iFoo = 42;
sFoo = "a string";
iBar = iFoo * 2;
```

I'm not saying this is a good idea, but rather that someone who is accustom to the language will be able to read this natively and think that it enhances readability while someone who isn't familiar with the language may think that it just adds a bunch of noise to the language.

However, after working with a language defined this way, I could probably read it without trouble.

Some people like them, some people don't.  There are great holy wars in various forums debating this and it really boils down to how much you've used them.

One could design a new language for non-programmers that uses sigils and anyone who has never programed before will never complain one bit about them.  On the other hand, you could not have them as part of the language and then have ruby or perl programers complain that they're missing out on some key information.

It really doesn't matter.  What does matter is how sigils would fit into the language if you use them or not.  Do you want to be able to do `"123 $foo 456"` or must you do `"123 " + foo + " 456"`?  This is where the decision should be made.

Comment: String interpolation such as `"123 $foo 456"` is not enabled by the sigil prefix and is completely orthogonal to it.

Comment: Its part of interpolation of variables and depends on how one parses a string.  Sigils can make that easier (it can be done other ways as shown by [Best way to do variable interpolation in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/) but that isn't part of the core language.  Sigils, arguably, make it much easier to write and understand this.

Comment: @MichaelT No, the fact that variables have prefixes do not make implementing string interpolation easier or harder. They are just 2 completely unrelated things. To a human reader, it might have been good choice to use `$asd` in the string interpolation syntax if `$` was already used for variable prefixes, but it had nothing to do with actual possiblity of implementing string interpolation in the first place.

Comment: @Esailija could you describe how they are unrelated?  As an aside, from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_interpolation - "Languages that support variable interpolation include Perl, PHP, Ruby, Tcl, Groovy, and most Unix shells. In these languages, variable interpolation only occurs when the string literal is double-quoted, but not when it is single-quoted. The variables are recognized because variables start with a sigil (typically "$") in these languages."

Comment: @MichaelT The dollar symbol being used in variable prefixes and string interpolation is completely superficial choice (which has only readability arguments, not anything to do with implementing, it might as well be `#` which is used in coffeescript for example. And coffeescript doesn't prefix variables with `#`-  in fact it doesn't prefix variables at all)

Comment: @MichaelT the sentence `The variables are recognized because variables start with a sigil (typically "$") in these languages.` is actually wrong and even contradicted in the article itself in the ruby section since `#` is not a sigil in ruby.

Comment: @Esailija, I very agree to each word of MichaelT but not to you.  $ or # or @ is not important, right. But I want very to see how YOU can parser "123 foo 456" without such symbol at all. Please?

Comment: Just from our own experience with our huge c++ projects. We do not use hungarian notation to underline types of variables. In C++ compiler helps a lots. But we using heavy prefixes to underline the scope of a variable: kCount, gCount, mCount, sCount, count, inCount, outCount, ioCount. Interesting, that couple years ago, I was need put hands on PHP code, and I have spend couple of days in refactoring adding such style to vars. This have helped a lots IMO. And I think this is not because of my habits. Just PHP now also have such scopes including classes.

Comment: @RuslanZasukhin You misunderstand greatly. I never said you can reliably do string interpolation without any symbol. I said that language sigils have nothing to do with string interpolation syntax. For, example, if we denote variables like `foo = 3`, `@foo = 3` or even `skoadkoasdoasDASKODASADSfoo = 3` that doesn't mean `"123 $foo 456"` wouldn't work. The prefix used or not used for the variable notation has nothing to do with the string interpolation syntax at any point when implementing it.

Comment: @esailija, okay, it seems you try say that a) language, e.g. PHP can not use $ at all, so everywhere variables will be as foo; b) but still possible to have string interpolation syntax IF require to use $ in this case only. Right?  Okay, I can agree with this.

Comment: @RuslanZasukhin yes, that is what I am saying.

Answer (score 3):

I not agree that PHP uses $ to differ vars from funcs. At least because PHP have C-like syntax, and funcs() have parens after the name.

Read this [post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073812/why-php-variables-start-with-a-sign-symbol) about why $ is in PHP.

Many popular languages, such as C, C++, C#, Java do not use $ and we can differ easy var from function.

In PHP $ helps, for example, when you write: 
  echo "var = $var"

Without $ such trick will be impossible.

Comment: +1 ah that does make more sense. Thanks.

Comment: A language having sigils has nothing to do with it having string interpolation as in your example of `echo "var = $var"`

Comment: -1. PHP syntax quirks are not because of some actual limitation but because the grammar rules are extremely poorly designed, if designed at all. This is why they need hacks to enable `fn()[]` where as with sensible grammar that would have worked out of the box without even thinking about it.

Comment: @svidgen Yes.  You cannot safely do string interpolation without some way to indicate what part of the string is supposed to map to a variable.  Other languages end up with what _I_ consider to be annoying/unnecessary verbosity, like Python's string formatting.  However, there are other advantages as well in PHP:  RuslanZasukhin is incorrect in saying that functions will always be indicated with parens, as they can also be passed around as references.

Comment: @Izkata The way you use variables in a language has nothing to do with string interpolation syntax. But that was implied in this answer, hence -1...

Comment: @Esailija Not directly, no, but then you end up with inconsistent representations of the same thing.

Comment: @Izkata How 'bout the annoying, unnecessary verbosity of escaping sigils :)

Comment: I'd certainly agree that having the sigil can make interpolation easier on the eyes ... but, it's by no means "impossible" without them, as the answer says.

Comment: @svidgen Well, you'd have to escape the substitution in string formatting anyway if you have a mix, creating even more inconsistent "If I do _A_, then I have to do _B_, but I'm not doing _A_, so I'm fine".

Comment: Hmm, I did say: "for example" and have mention only one feature where $ helps.  In C++ we cannot write such syntax. I did not say that $ was added into PHP because of this. But this works.

With same success, I will say that $return was no intention of PHP developer. This is obvious side effect from parser. 

Also in link to other post you could read info which others have duplicate in answers, e.g. that PHP have inherit this from Perl.

Answer (score 3):

...a sigil allows to:

- Better **distinguish variables from non-variables**. People that are still learning basic concepts might have trouble figuring out which words are variables and which don't. They often start by reading examples or other people's code with no adequate background.
- Use **reserved keywords** or **function names** as **variable names**. At times I found some of those names to be the right ones for a variable (i.e. `$count` while there was a `count()` function defined) and thanked sigils for allowing me to use them.

> Also I happen to do that *function name reusing* frequently, for holding a function's result in a throwaway variable, e.g.:
>
> `$isdir=isdir($dir);`
>
> `if(/* complex condition implying $isdir */) {`
>      `/* etc */`
>      `}`

Comment: ZHR, what means better? In C++ we write all our variables without $ and we perfectly and easy distinguish them. Example: { int z = 0; z = 55; z(z); }   And in C++ we also can use function name if need to assign, for example pointer to function.

Comment: @RuslanZasukhin, Computer illiterates, do you know some? Try teaching them C++, you'll be amazed.

Comment: Also: I don't think a sigil must always be a `$` sign. I remember the dollar sign confusing me when I was a kid because of its inherent money association. `%` might be a feasible alternative.

Answer (score 3):

After all this answers, I want give some more points to Mathew Foscarini.

- You consider problem now as a "language constructor". You try understand why another language have this or that feature to choose if to use something in your own language. I am in same position many years, because developing SQL parser for our Valentina Database.
- I advice you take a look on antlr.org and even read book from Terence. It has a lots nice things for language developers.
- I still not agree to "reasons" exposed by other answers. They assume that PHP author in head have decide to use $ to be able use reserved keywords and Better distinguish variables from non-variables. I do not think so ... although prove can be only his/their own story.
- Most probably that they just follow to perl and more early languages. As underlines Terrence, most languages are similar, especially in LEXER part. And usually constructor of a new language can just choose what kind of language he is going to develop and then take lexer of that language grammar. And this is what you should do now. No need invent from scratch. And I bet the same did PHP authors.
- All else what people mention:

  - distinguish variables from non-variables
  - reserver words as variable names
  - ability to place variable inside of string
  - may be else (I am not big expert in PHP)

are **side-effects of this LEXER**, because it is able to recognize a token.

Take as example: in SQL we use "" to be able to use identifiers with reserved words and even identifiers with spaces "First Name", "Group Name". GROUP is a keyword. There was problem - there was special solution.

P.S. Very good comment from MichaelT.

Comment: +1 thanks for the great link. I ended up using this one, but your link looks a lot better. http://goldparser.org/

Comment: Thank you also for your link. I have not see this gold parser one before. Looks also interesting.

Comment: @RuslanZasukhin if you are making a reference to my answer, I never said it was developer's intention to enable keywords. I only said that using keywords as variables names becomes technically possible when variables are prefixed with a symbol like `$`. Also the *"ability to place variable inside string"* is not because of variables being prefixed with a symbol like `$`. That is, `"123 $foo 456"` will work if even if variable syntax is like `foo = 3` or `@foo = 3`. They are not related to each other.